# How to fetch data for 30 days from current date

Tags: oracle, db2

I am fetching data from DB2 database. I want pull the data for only past 30 days. How can it be done ?
I tried the below query but it is giving me the data from 6th June to  30th June. but I want the data from 11 June to 11 July - Exact 30 days. Substring is used to convert the DB2  timestamp.

```
select TO_DATE (   SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 4, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 6, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 2)
                        || '  '
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 8, 2)
                        || ':00',
                        'MM/DD/YY  HH24:MI'
                       ) as create_date, * from  xyz WHERE TO_DATE (   SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 4, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 6, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 2)
                        || '  '
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 8, 2)
                        || ':00',
                        'MM/DD/YY  HH24:MI'
                       ) > add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and TO_DATE (   SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 4, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 6, 2)
                        || '/'
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 2)
                        || '  '
                        || SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 8, 2)
                        || ':00',
                        'MM/DD/YY  HH24:MI'
                       ) < trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Comment: The question mentions DB2 but is tagged Oracle. Which is it?

Comment: i am pulling data from DB2 to oracle.

Comment: What is the "Timestamp" column's format? You're converting it to MM/DD/YY HH24:MI, so all those SUBSTRs should make sure that you really extracted data in that format.

Comment: Issue is not with the Timestamps format, that is working fine. I just want to know how to pull data for past 30 days.

Comment: I need solution on the 'where' part of the query

Comment: Couldn't all that concatenation be written more simply as `to_date(substr("Timestamp",2,8),'YYMMDDHH24')`?

Comment: If you want to go back 30 days, use `sysdate -30` not `add_months(sysdate, -1)`. (This is how it works in Oracle at least. I'm still not sure how DB2 fits into the question.)

Comment: Yes, it can be written as (TO_DATE(SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 12),'YYMMDD HH24MISS')) as well. I need to change that. But first need the solution to the 'where' part of the query.

Comment: I tried with sysdate - 30 but getting some DB2 error : WHERE (TO_DATE(SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 12),'YYMMDD HH24MISS')) > (sysdate - 30)) a where 1=0  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-182, SQLSTATE=42816, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.64.114 (code:7034)

Comment: Where did the `) a where 1=0` part come from? Is this an inline view in a bigger query/ (1=0 is never true so it would never return anything anyway...)

Comment: This is a way of telling that the query is wrong :) , as you said, where 1=0 is never true.

Comment: the main error is Error: SQLCODE=-182, SQLSTATE=42816, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.64.114

Answer (score 0):

Instead of " < trunc(sysdate, 'mm')" use " between add_months(sysdate, -1) and sysdate"

Comment: This is giving data from 1st june to 11th july

Comment: @Priyam - did you leave in the `trunc(...,'MM')` part by mistake? This gives you a full month though, which isn't always 30 days. Depends which you actually want.

Comment: Yes its giving for a full month, but I want for only 30 days.

Comment: @Priyam between add_months(sysdate, -1) and sysdate will be like 11-06-2018 and 11-07-2018

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your help. I got the solution`Where (TO_DATE(SUBSTR ("Timestamp", 2, 12),'YYMMDD HH24MISS')) > (current_date - 30 days)`

Comment: `30 days` is not valid unless you've used the `INTERVAL` keyword. `current_date - 30` is enough.